# Not sure how this inout scenario is safe, because the array gets invalidated upon return

Tags: arrays, swift, invalidation

The below code doesn't crash, but I can't reason why, given the "limited" docs available.

```
func foo(inout a: [Int], inout b: Int) {
    a = []
    b = 99
}

var arr = [1,2,3]

// confusion: where does the "out" of b go to?
// storage for a was already cleared / invalidated
foo(&arr, b: &arr[2])

print(arr)  // arr is empty
```

Comment: that's interesting. did you try it with different levels of optimization ? INOUT parameters are first copied then processed and finally copied back. how the copy is implemented, who knows?

Comment: yeah I compiled with and without -O, same result.  swift 2.1.

Comment: i have the same results. maybe the idea is not to copy back the result if 'out of bound' by default ...

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what is happening.  When you assign

```
a = []
```

you are pointing `a` to an new array.  The original array still exists in memory and when you do:

```
b = 99
```

you are modifying the original array, not the new array that `a` references.

> What evidence do you have that this is the case?

Consider this modification to your experiment:

**Case 1:**

```
func foo(inout a: [Int], inout b: Int) {
    a[0] = 4
    a[1] = 5
    a[2] = 6
    b = 99
}

var arr = [1,2,3]

foo(&arr, b: &arr[2])

print(arr)  // prints "[4, 5, 99]"
```

Now consider this one:

**Case 2:**

```
func foo(inout a: [Int], inout b: Int) {
    a = [4, 5, 6]
    b = 99
}

var arr = [1,2,3]

foo(&arr, b: &arr[2])

print(arr)  // prints "[4, 5, 6]"
```

Clearly, modifying the individual elements of `a` is not the same as assigning an array to `a`.

In Case 1, we modified the original array turning the elements into `4`, `5`, and `6`, and the assignment of `b` changed `a[2]` as expected.

In Case 2, we assigned `[4, 5, 6]` to `a` which didn't change the original values to `4`, `5`, and `6` but instead pointed `a` to a new array.  The assignment of `b` does not change `a[2]` in this case because `a` now points to a new array at a different location in memory.

**Case 3:**

```
func foo(inout a: [Int], inout b: Int) {
    let a1 = a
    a = [4, 5, 6]
    b = 99
    print(a)   // prints "[4, 5, 6]"
    print(a1)  // prints "[1, 2, 99]"
}

var arr = [1,2,3]

foo(&arr, b: &arr[2])

print(arr)  // prints "[4, 5, 6]"
```

In Case 3, we are able to assign the original array to `a1` before assigning a new array to `a`.  This gives us a name for the original array.  When `b` is assigned, `a1[2]` gets modified.

---

From the comments:

> Your answer explains why the assignment to b inside the function
>   works. However, when foo ends and copies the inout variables back, at
>   that point I don't see how swift knows to defer deallocating the
>   original array until after the &[2] assignment.

It is likely that this is a result of reference counting by ARC.  The original array is passed by reference to `foo` and the reference count is incremented.  The original array isn't deallocated until the reference count is decremented at the end of `foo`.

> It seems just as hairy as what the docs already disallow - passing the
>   same variable twice as inout. Also your case3 is surprising. Shouldn't
>   the let a1 = a line do struct / value semantics and copy a snapshot of
>   the array right then?

Yes. I agree that Case 3 is surprising, but it does reveal some of what is going on under the covers. Normally when you assign one array to a new variable, Swift does not immediately make a copy.  Instead, it just points the second array to the first and the reference count incremented. This is done for efficiency sake. It is only necessary to make a copy when one of the arrays is modified. In this case, when `a` gets modified, `a1` keeps the original copy of the array in memory.

> That's really confusing; I don't see why a1 wouldn't get 1,2,3. Also a
>   let should be immutable!

The fact that `a1` gets modified when `b` is set shows that `a1` is pointing to the memory of the original array. Swift apparently doesn't consider setting `b` as modifying `a1`. Perhaps because it already made sure `a` was mutable when `foo` was called with `&a[2]`.

Comment: Your answer explains why the assignment to b inside the function works.  However, when foo ends and copies the inout variables back, at that point I don't see how swift knows to defer deallocating the original array until after the `&[2]` assignment.  It seems just as hairy as what the docs already disallow - passing the same variable twice as inout.

Also your case3 is surprising.   Shouldn't the `let a1 = a` line do struct / value semantics and copy a snapshot of the array right then?   That's really confusing; I don't see why a1 wouldn't get `1,2,3`.  Also a `let` should be immutable!

Comment: Yes.  I agree that Case 3 is surprising, but it does reveal some of what is going on under the covers.  Normally when you assign one array to a new variable, Swift does not immediately make a copy.  Instead, it just points the second array to the first and the reference count incremented.  This is done for efficiency sake.  It is only necessary to make a copy when one of the arrays is modified.  In this case, when `a` gets modified, `a1` keeps the original copy of the array in memory.

Comment: The fact that `a1` gets modified when `b` is set shows that `a1` is pointing to the memory of the original array.  Swift apparently doesn't consider setting `b` as modifying `a1`.  Perhaps because it already made sure `a` was mutable when `foo` was called with `&a[2]`.